# Extending the function prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm looking to be able to extend the function prototype in javascript (that is to say, add a function to all functions).
The purpose is to convert it into a format for exchange between another language (namely ruby, which can only communicate through strings [in this particular setting]). I've already got a system so I can pass around other types by defining a `to_js` method on ruby objects and a `to_ruby` method on javascript objects, like so

```
Number.prototype.to_ruby = function () { return this.toString(); }
```

This is working for everything else I want it to, but not for functions. I *can* get it to work in chrome by doing the following:

```
_empty = function() {};
_empty.__proto__.to_ruby = function () {
    return 'JSFunction.new(' + this.toString().to_ruby() + ')';
};
```

But this does not work in IE (which is a requirement of the system).

I know I have an object somewhere keeping a track of functions by an ID or similar, but I can't guarantee that they will be used with the same instance that created them.

All else failing I could just write a function to special case deal with it (ie, `isFunction(instance) ? fn_to_ruby(instance) : instance.to_ruby()`, but I'd rather keep this model if possible.

Comment: Hah! I just happen to be looking into the same thing. SketchUp Ruby <-> JavaScript bridge. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__proto__` is not a standard property. Try this approach:

```
(function(){}).constructor.prototype.to_ruby = function(){
    return 'JSFunction.new(' + this.toString().to_ruby() + ')';
};
```

Comment: Ah! Adding the `.constructor` gives me the functionality I was looking for - thanks!

Comment: You must get paid by the character. `(function(){}).constructor.prototype` is just `Function.prototype`. And calling `someObj.to_ruby()` will be identical to `"" + someObj`

Comment: @RobG, you are correct - and of course now that I ca see it, it makes perfect sense. thanks :)

Comment: @RobG, don't get the point: `""+someObj`, with `someObj={a:1,b:2}` returns `"[object Object]"` to me. and `({a:1,b:2}).prototype` resolve to undefined

Comment: @Eineki—yeah, should have used `someFn` since the OP is about Functions, but you can replace `Object.prototype.toString` with a more suitable method (but be careful about sharing such code).

Answer (score 5):

As Slace said, you can add the method to all Objects by adding it to `Object.prototype`, but that isn't really kosher as it may affect badly written for..in loops.

You can add it just to functions via `Function.prototype`:

```
Function.prototype.to_ruby = function() {
  return this.toString();
}
```

However there is a general rule that you shouldn't modify built-in objects, mostly because you never know when it will come back to haunt you (e.g. a new version of ECMAScript implements a property with the same name). Perhaps you are better off to write a single `toRuby` function:

```
function toRuby(obj) {
  return obj.toString();
}
```

but you can also also use the `+` operator to concatenate with a string to call the `toString` method implicitly:

```
'' + obj; // returns obj.toString()
```

which will return exactly the same result as both the above. Your choice.

Comment: I understand your argument, but I've got a number of different types of objects that all need to return slightly differently.
So this would work for basic types like numbers and strings (assuming they don't need to be escaped) but for arrays, hash-like objects and custom types I'd have to write a special case for each, and continue to edit that as I require more or less objects.

Comment: In that case you can write a single `toRuby()` function and tell it how to convert the passed object, e.g. `toRuby(someFn, 'fn')`, `toRuby(someObj, 'obj')` or similar.

Comment: That's what I originally had, but as the number of possible object types increased I figured it would just be easier to have a to_ruby method on objects that supported the conversion. That way I could easily test for support as well as perform the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

The `__proto__` is not part of any JavaScript standard it's just a pesudo-standard that some of the browser manufacturers have decided to implement. IE is one that *hasn't* implemented it.

If you want to modify *any* type in the JavaScript type system then you'll have to modify the `Object` prototype:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function () { console.log('foo'); };
(1).foo();
'asd'.foo();
(true).foo();
({ bar: 'baz' }).foo();
```