# How to access exported "nested" functions in Nodejs - TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a case of exported nested modules:

### BaseTutorial.js

```
// exports module makes the functions public such that they can be accessed in other modules in Node.js.
module.exports.fun_tutorial = function()
{
    console.log("First print from Tutorial.js")                                
}
```

### Extended_NodeTutorial.js

```
    // `require` is the way to include other modules in

var obj_baseTutorialJS = require('./Base_Tutorial.js');

module.exports.fun_extendedNodeTutorial = function()
{
    console.log("Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js")

    this.ss = function fun_nested()         
    {
        console.log("sadasdsa")
        var fun_nested = obj_baseTutorialJS
        fun_nested.fun_tutorial();
    }
}
```

### app.js

```
var obj_extendedNodeTutorial = require('./Extended_NodeTutorial.js');
console.log(obj_extendedNodeTutorial)

obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial();
obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested();
```

### Error after executing `node app.js`:

```
{ fun_extendedNodeTutorial: [Function] }
Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js
/home/***/Documents/home_notes/MEAN/app.js:7
obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested();
                                                  ^

TypeError: obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/***/Documents/home_notes/MEAN/app.js:7:51)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

---

Comment: This is not related to the "modules" topic. `fun_extendedNodeTutorial` function has no member named `fun_nested`. It only has a member with name `ss` which points to a named function.

Comment: Do you not considered work with classes and use extends concept?

Comment: The question as it is now is very vague, What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It would be good if you use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve but there are multiple ways you can solve this problem.

### 1) You can return your nested function.

**BaseTutorial.js**

```js
module.exports.fun_tutorial = function()
{
    console.log("First print from Tutorial.js")                                
}
```

**Extended_NodeTutorial.js**

```js
var obj_baseTutorialJS = require('./Base_Tutorial.js');

module.exports.fun_extendedNodeTutorial = function()
{
    console.log("Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js");

    return fun_nested()
    {
        console.log("sadasdsa");
        const fun_tutorial = obj_baseTutorialJS.fun_tutorial;
        fun_tutorial();
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```js
var obj_extendedNodeTutorial = require('./Extended_NodeTutorial.js');
console.log(obj_extendedNodeTutorial)

const fun_nested = obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial();
fun_nested(); // adasdsa
```

### 2) You can create an instance of the function exported from `Extended_NodeTutorial.js`. I see you're trying to use `this.ss`. To achive something similar to that you'll have to make use of `new` keyword.

**BaseTutorial.js**

```
module.exports.fun_tutorial = function()
{
    console.log("First print from Tutorial.js")                                
}
```

**Extended_NodeTutorial.js**

```js
var obj_baseTutorialJS = require('./Base_Tutorial.js');

module.exports.fun_extendedNodeTutorial = function()
{
    console.log("Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js")

    this.fun_nested = function()
    {
        console.log("sadasdsa");
        const fun_nested = obj_baseTutorialJS.fun_tutorial;
        fun_tutorial();
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```js
var obj_extendedNodeTutorial = require('./Extended_NodeTutorial.js');
console.log(obj_extendedNodeTutorial)

const fun_extendedNodeTutorial = new obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial(); // Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js
fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested(); // sadasdsa
```

Answer (score 1):

This a prototype inheritance issue. You should either use [`constructor.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10528557/1889685) to define your `fun_nested` function and use it whenever you want:

```js
var obj_baseTutorialJS = require('./Base_Tutorial.js');

module.exports.fun_extendedNodeTutorial = function()
{
    console.log("Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js")
}

module.exports.fun_extendedNodeTutorial.constructor.prototype.fun_nested = function() {
    console.log("sadasdsa")
    var fun_nested = obj_baseTutorialJS
    fun_nested.fun_tutorial();
}
```

and use it like this:

```js
obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial();
obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested();
```

or if you define `fun_nested` inside `fun_extendedNodeTutorial` using `this.ss`:

```js
module.exports.fun_extendedNodeTutorial = function()
{
    console.log("Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js")

    this.ss = function fun_nested()         
    {
        console.log("sadasdsa")
        var fun_nested = obj_baseTutorialJS
        fun_nested.fun_tutorial();
    }
}
```

then create an instance of `fun_extendedNodeTutorial` function and use `ss` to call `fun_nested` function:

```js
var extendedNodeTutorial = new obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial();
extendedNodeTutorial.ss();
```

Both ways will output everything in order:

```
$ node .\app.js
{ fun_extendedNodeTutorial: [Function] }
Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js
sadasdsa
First print from Tutorial.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to advise you since there are many different implementations of nested functions/imports, and the appropriate one largely depends on your use case. I took a guess that you would like to allow access to an imported module from another imported module, and that you'd like to use `app.js` as written.

You can expose certain variables or modules by setting a property to the exported variable (or in this case, a function). For this example, it would be something like `fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested = obj_baseTutorialJS.fun_tutorial;`

### BaseTutorial.js

```
// As previously written
module.exports.fun_tutorial = function()
{
    console.log("First print from Tutorial.js")                                
}
```

### Extended_NodeTutorial.js

```
var obj_baseTutorialJS = require('./Base_Tutorial.js');

// we'll store fun_extendedNodeTutorial to a variable to later
// assign a property to it
var fun_extendedNodeTutorial = function()
{
    console.log("Second print from Extended_NodeTutorial.js")
}

// this allows outside files to access fun_tutorial via
// fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested
fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested = obj_baseTutorialJS.fun_tutorial;

// finally export the function and its nested property
module.exports.fun_extendedNodeTutorial = fun_extendedNodeTutorial;
```

### app.js

```
// As previously written
var obj_extendedNodeTutorial = require('./Extended_NodeTutorial.js');
console.log(obj_extendedNodeTutorial)

obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial();
obj_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_extendedNodeTutorial.fun_nested();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight modification that will not cause the error:
**abc.js**

```js
module.exports.test = () => {
  this.ss = function () {
    return 'From ss'
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```js
const abc = require('./abc')
abc.test()
abc.ss()
```

Basically, when we replace the function keyword with a fat arrow in the `abc.js` file, the `this` keyword is bound lexically, which means it is bound to the module.exports object of abc.js . From `app.js`, we first require `abc.js` and then run the `test` method. This will populate the exported object `abc` with the function `ss` and you can now access it via the `abc` object.

When we run it with the following command,

```sh
node app.js
```

We get the string `From ss`